# python sum of funtions incorrect answer for s(2)

Tags: python

```
Using s(2)

def factfirst(n):
initalvalue=1

for y in range(1,2*n):
    initalvalue=initalvalue*y
return initalvalue

def powerfirst(n) :
return (-1)**(n-1)

def firstxpower(n) :
return (2*n)-1

def s(x) :
for n in range(1,x+1):
    total=0
    total+=(powerfirst(n)/factfirst(n))*(x**firstxpower(n))
return total
print(s(2))
```

I keep getting -1.3333 and should be getting .90929 when worked out on calculator, can anyone tell me what is incorrect?

Comment: Have you checked each intermediate step to determine at what point things go wrong?

Comment: You should also check indentation

Comment: Scott is right. You should help us helping you by debugging the program as much as possible on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code, you are setting `total = 0` in the loop, so total will always be 0 at the start and when the loop finishes it will give the last number.

Should be like:

```
def s(x) :
    total=0
    for n in range(1,x+1):
        total+=(powerfirst(n)/factfirst(n))*(x**firstxpower(n))
    return total
print(s(2))
```

Comment: well it is getting closer but I am getting .666 moving the total=0 up a line but still not .909

Comment: I am trying to compute the sum of a special series with n=1

Comment: it is this function:

Comment: Are you sure '(powerfirst(n)/factfirst(n))*(x**firstxpower(n))' is correct? when I tried '(powerfirst(n)/factfirst(n))**(x**firstxpower(n))' I got 0.9999994046258193 and when '(powerfirst(n)/factfirst(n))**(**firstxpower(n))' I got 0.9953703703703703

Comment: S(x) = ∑∞n=1((-1)n-1/((2n-1)!))x2n-1 where n=1 is actually the subscript of the sum sign.

Comment: 2n-1 is factorial but you are not calculating it

Comment: s(x) = sum sign upper limit infinity lower limit n=1

Comment: Understood that but what I am saying your functions need modifications they are not exactly doing what is asked here

Comment: rest of equation is (((-1) ^n-1)/(2n-1)!) all multiplied by x^2n-1

Comment: how is it calculated?